# Can we create duplicate rows in Oracle sql without using join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in 2 tables which are not linked. These needs to merged by duplicating the row values.

Example

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “without using join”? What you show is a Cartesian join - the basis of all joins.

Comment: there was no primary key to join the tables... as suggested I used cross join and have got the desired output

Comment: I don't see any duplicate row in your expected output as you asked in your question title. I only see cartesian product with 12 distinct rows. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I was not aware of the cartesian join. My question was on these lines only, but might have framed it incorrectly.  This is answered now.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for CROSS JOIN to achieve the resultset you want.

`SELECT Date, Dept, Location, code
FROM TableA CROSS JOIN TableB`

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Without Join, Try following Code.

```
SELECT Date, Dept, Location, code
FROM TableA ,TableB
```

Comment: How is that "without join"? What you have is a join (using Oracle syntax, but still a join). Downvoted, since the answer is not helpful; perhaps best if you delete it altogether.

Comment: WITH TABLEA AS (SELECT '01-JAN-20' DATE1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-FEB-20' DATE1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT '01-MAR-20' DATE1 FROM DUAL),

TableB as (SELECT 'A' Dept,'A1' Location,'RET' Code from dual
union all
SELECT 'B' Dept,'B2' Location,'CTE' Code from dual
union all
SELECT 'C' Dept,'C1' Location,'PST' Code from dual
union all
SELECT 'D' Dept,'D4' Location,'GGO' Code from dual)
select * from tablea,tableb

First check  this query and execute then give me voted ok. . they have give me proper answer. i am optimize my query.